# Trouble rendering data attributes in Haml, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I've been trying to convert the following from html.erb to html.haml, but things aren't rendering 100% correctly.  Specifically I'm wondering how to correctly write the bit of code within the script tags in Haml.

html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <h4>So what comes with being a Blocipedia premium member? </h4>
  <p>The ability to create your very OWN private wikis of course!</p>
  <script class='stripe-button' src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" data-key="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:key] %>" data-amount=<%= @stripe_btn_data[:amount] %> data-description="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:description] %>" ></script>
<% end %>
```

html.haml:

```
= form_tag charges_path do
  %h4 So what comes with being a Blocipedia premium member?
  %p The ability to create your very OWN private wikis of course!
  %script.stripe-button{"data-key" => @stripe_btn_data[:key], :src => "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js", "data_amount" => @stripe_btn_data[:amount], "data_description" => @stripe_btn_data[:description]}
```

Before I tried to rewrite my code in Haml, my original html.erb file rendered like so below.

Before Haml (The way my page SHOULD render):

[image: Correct]

Yet after trying to change to Haml, I was not 100% successful in getting the page to render in exactly the same way

After Haml (notice the data-amount ($15.00) and the data-discription (BigMoney Membership) aren't being displayed)

[image: Incorrect]

What is the correct Haml syntax to render this page properly?

**Update**

I'm trying to grab the data-amount and description from my charges_controller.rb

charges_controller.rb:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Creates a Stripe Customer object, for associating with the charge
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Where the real magic happens
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id, # Note -- this is NOT the user_id in your app
      amount: Amount.default,
      description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.email}",
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for all the money, #{current_user.email}!  You now have a premium Blocipedia account!  Feel free to pay me again."

    current_user.update_attribute(:role, "premium")

    redirect_to root_path # Or wherever

    # Stripe will send back CardErrors, with friendly messages when something goes wrong.
    # This rescue block catches and displays those errors.
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  def new
    @stripe_btn_data = {
      key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
      description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.name}",
      amount: Amount.default
    }
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user.update_attributes(role: "standard")
      flash[:notice] = "You now have a standard Blocipedia account.  Feel free to upgrade back to premium at anytime!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error downgrading your account.  Please contact technical support."
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

amount.rb:

```
class Amount
  def self.default
    15_00
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see the `BigMoney Membership` code in both `erb` and `haml`

Comment: I'm trying to reference the data-description and data-amount my charges_controller.rb file via my @stripe_btn_data instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the same HTML output of ERB using HAML

```
= form_tag charges_path do
  %h4 So what comes with being a Blocipedia premium member?
  %p The ability to create your very OWN private wikis of course!
  %script.stripe-button{data: {key: @stripe_btn_data[:key], amount: @stripe_btn_data[:amount], description: @stripe_btn_data[:description]}, src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what I was looking for.